# How can I confine my pet rock mole?

Tags: nethack

I sort of like my pet rock mole because she chews up all the dungeon levels. But I don't like the way she keeps burrowing toward my stash area when I am organizing things.

Is there some way to keep my pet rock mole confined to an area, while still keeping her on the same dungeon level as me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is surround the rock mole with cursed items, as pets won't step on them.

I imagine that a rock mole may still eat cursed metallic items, so you would want to do this with elven daggers, slings, or anything else that's non-metallic.

Something like this:

```
))))))
)  r )
))))))
```

(Those would all be cursed elven daggers, or similar.)

Comment: This is a good idea. I don't have a suitable pile of cursed items at the moment, but I expect i can make one soon. I'll accept your answer after I prove to myself it really works. Thanks!

Comment: My rock mole died before I could experiment with this approach. The idea is sound, so I "accept".